# Swift process causes my MacBook Pro 2019 to freeze

Tags: macos, freeze, xcode

After updating to macOS Catalina and Xcode 11 my MacBook Pro 2019 i9 keeps freezing after working with Xcode for a while.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Answer (score 3):

I know that there was quite a time from this question were posted but I have the same issue with the same machine. I've found that disabling the build parallelization improves the performance.
You will need go to your App target -> Edit scheme -> Build -> Uncheck 'Parallelize Build'

It's weird because on my old i7 MacBook pro it works just fine.

You can find this option here:
[image: Image with the location of "Parallelize Build" option]

Comment: i don't do that but i did Reset NVRAM or PRAM & my issue fixed